# How does a program know where the bss segment is located

Tags: c, memory-management

As far as i have understood x86 has dedicated registers for pointers to code-, data- and stack segment, but not bss- and heap segment. How does the computer remember where these segments are? Especially heap, since bss is directly after data, but heap often is placed a different place in memory.

Comment: You have a major misconception here. These segments need not be remembered in the run-time. They are just used to allocate variables in. And each variable has an address which is located in that segment.

Comment: But how can the same code be ran in different places in memory, if it does not have pointers which stores segment "offset"?

Comment: It can't unless compiled as "relocatable".

Comment: The heap is usually created by the C runtine which is linked with your code (statically or dynamically). It decides an address in the virtual address, calls the operating system provided system calls to map pages and stores the address in some data structure which is used by malloc (and family of functions) as heap.

Comment: All this code is either executed before calling main or is statically initialized in the binary.

Comment: The bss segment is normally folded into the data segment after the executable is loaded. The rest of the runtime isn't affected by this. The variables are located at an appropriate address regardless of where it came from in the executable.

Comment: As for the bss section, As you know it is filled with all zeroes. The binary has information on the size of the .bss section and the base address. The loader maps pages to this virtual address and clears them with zeroes (in an efficient way).

Comment: I think i understand what i dont understand, now (if you understand what i mean). I hadnt read about relocatable programs and virtuel addresses. Thanks for the help

Comment: You can see the address of the bss segment and its size by running `dumpbin /HEADERS binary.exe` if on windows. On Linux you can use `objdump`. I believe the required flag is `-x`.

Comment: If you were wanting to lay out memory in a specific manner, then you pass a linker command file (usually has the extension: `.cmd`) to the linker.  This is most useful when there are memory mapped I/O, memory mapped special registers, memory mapped ROM and FLASH, memory mapped peripheral registers, etc,  Most often used when creating executables for (bare metal) embedded systems.  Here is a link to more info for a GNU linker command file: (others are similar) 'https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The heap is usually created by the C runtine which is linked with your code (statically or dynamically). It decides an address in the virtual address, calls the operating system provided system calls to map pages and stores the address in some data structure which is used by malloc (and family of functions) as heap. 
All this code is either executed before calling main or is statically initialized in the binary.

As for the bss section, As you know it is filled with all zeroes. The binary has information on the size of the .bss section and the base address. The loader maps pages to this virtual address and clears them with zeroes (in an efficient way).

You can see the address of the bss segment and its size by running `dumpbin /HEADERS binary.exe` if on windows. On Linux you can use `objdump`. I believe the required flag is `-x`.

About your question that how can they be moved around if the offsets are hard coded in the instructions -

The binary also has a table called the relocation table which has addresses of all instructions that access these values on a particular section. The loader may decide to place the segment somewhere else (usually happens when you load multiple dlls or shared libraries in Linux). 
In that case it patches all the instructions looking at the relocation table. It actually changes the offsets in the instruction. This is done by the loader before executing the `main`.

Ofcourse this has an overhead and can be done only if the relocation information is available. Some binaries may choose to omit the relocation table and in that case the binary fails loading if the section cannot be placed at the specified location.

Hope that clears some of the confusion.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explenation. Is there any name for this topic, which i can use to find resources? The topic of how compilers and operatingsystems manage memory

Comment: You can read about "linkers and loaders". I don't really have links to resources. For structure of the binary you can read about the ELF file format. It is the most commonly used. Other one is COFF.

Comment: One last question. If this is the process  of how code is ran, and the code has static knowlage of where the segments are, why do you have segment registers at all?

Comment: Segment registers really hasn't got anything to do with these segments. The segment registers __were__ used in segmented memory models. Modern architectures (like x86_64) use paging and a flat memory model, where the entire Virtual address is accessible to the program and it can decide how it wants to use it. To answer in short, the segment registers are not used anymore. The base of cs, ds segments is always set to 0 on x86_64.

Comment: If on x86 your program does use segment registers, the bss and heap are usually combined with other .data and .rodata sections as a part of the memory under the data segment. The cs is for code(.text section in the binary), and stack is well for the stack!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the simple answer is that the "bss segment" is just a number in the executable that tells the loader how much data at a minimum to reserve for the zero-initialized global data. Nothing more.

After having reserved and set to zero this memory, the run-time start-up of the program (be it compiled from Fortran, C or whatever for the particular platform), now reserves more memory and sets up the heap there and next decides where the stack is to go. Following more platform specific initializiation, control is finally transfered to the program entry point as indicated in the executable file, and control is transfered to there. Only now is the program "live".

Answer (score -1):

> As far as i have understood x86 has dedicated registers for pointers to code-, data- and stack segment, but not bss- and heap segment. How does the computer remember where these segments are? Especially heap, since bss is directly after data, but heap often is placed a different place in memory.

You are suffering for overlapping terminology. A segment can refer to memory segment under the segmented memory model (as used in pre-64-bit X86). A segment can also refer to an block of memory with common access attributes created by a linker.

Your question appears to refer to the second usage.

You also appear to suffer from an oversimplified view of memory. First of all, there is no heap segment. A heap is one or more blocks of read/write data.

Second, a linker can create multiple demand zero (bss) segments. A linker can also put the segments in any order in memory

Third, the knowledge of segments is only needed at load time. Once the segments are loaded, they are just memory.